# Is there XML binding library for Ruby (like JAXB)?

Tags: ruby, xml, serialization, xsd

is there any tool for Ruby which can transform XML (SOAP) to objects and vice versa? And if possible, generate all the objects (models) from XML schema (XSD). I worked several times with JAXB tool (in Java) and I need something simmilar:

- generate models from XML schema
- easily create component for serializing and deserializing them
- easily create component for storing the objects to database
- if possible, generate database tables according to that schema

Do you know any tool for this? What approach would you recommend to complete such task?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Savon](http://savonrb.com/) should cover SOAP part of it.

Comment: btw. savon converts xml to and from ruby hashes, but it still requires some low-level knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it but there is a library called HappyMapper: http://happymapper.rubyforge.org/

Comment: It looks nice, does it provide automatic object creating from XML schema?

Comment: Note that the maintained version is [nokogiri-happymapper](https://github.com/dam5s/happymapper). It doesn't automatically create objects for you, though, and some of the bugs were showstoppers for me (but might not be for you). I switched to [xml-mapper](https://github.com/multi-io/xml-mapping), which has a clunkier syntax but didn't have any showstopper bugs -- but unfortunately it doesn't automatically generate mapping classes for you either.